# C# format currency with leading spaces?

Tags: c#, string, formatting, currency

I am trying to duplicate a text report that was written in Icon in C#. The report has:

```
Blah Blah........ $  10,938.09
Blah Blah........ $       3.88
Blah Blah........ $ 102,398.11
```

I am able to use multiple formatting calls to achieve this result with out issue, for example:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Blah Blah.....${0,10}", number.ToString("#,##0.00")));
```

but I would think there is a way to do it with just one call to string.Format(). Any idea how to insert leading spaces in a currency format?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You do it like so:

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Blah Blah.....${0,10:#,##0.00}", number));
```

**Update:**

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fht0f5be.aspx#978a52f8-38a5-4823-9b02-2398c9bcefbb) is the relevant part of the documentation.